# Why is git merging things which I have not modified?

Tags: git

I have a problem with a git merge where it is saying there is a conflict between a file change and a rename operation. The branching was done something like this:

1. base -> more_design
2. several changes in more_design
3. more_design -> fixed_toolbar
4. fixed_toolbar minimal changes (no changes in PNG files)
5. modify PNG files in more_design
6. rebase more_design to base (no changes in PNG files)
7. attempt to merge from fixed_toolbar (git gets confused on PNG files)

A sample of the errors:

```
Auto-merging ui-app/css/images/icons-retina/item-unselected.png
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in ui-app/css/images/icons-retina/item-unselected.png
CONFLICT (rename/delete): ui-app/css/images/icons-retina/item-selected.png deleted in HEAD and renamed in fixed_toolbar. Version fixed_toolbar of ui-app/css/images/icons-retina/item-selected.png left in tree.
```

And when I try to accept our version it says there is no such version (yet they are definitely there in the branch):

```
git checkout --ours -- ui-app/css/images/icons-retina/item-*.png
error: path 'ui-app/css/images/icons-retina/item-unselected.png' does not have our version
error: path 'ui-app/css/images/icons-retina/item-selected.png' does not have our version
```

Comment: Your conflicts are in item-unselected and item-selected. Your checkout command complains about item-cancel and item-collapse. Why would that checkout command not complain, if that's what you are passing on the command line? Remember, wildcards get expanded by looking at files on your filesystem, not on the files in git.

Comment: Sorry, these are just snippets of the long list of PNG files that actually conflict. Rest assured that all those error lines appear for all of the files (I'll update the question to choose better lines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **Rebase and merge don't mix!**

Never ever branch from something that might be rebased and/or never rebase anything that might be branched from!

You have history like:

```
base - b1 - b2 - b3 - 
  \               \
   \              more_design' - m1' - m2' - m3' - m4' >?
    \                                               ..
    more_design - m1 - m2 - m3 - m4              ..  
                        \                      ..
                        fixed_toolbar - f1 - f2
```

Rebasing `more_design` above created completely new version of the history. Instead of *m1..m4* you now have *m1'..m4'*. These are completely distinct revisions as far as git is concerned. So the most recent common ancestor is *base*! Therefore "local" changes is *m1'+m2'+m3'+m4'* and "remote" changes is *m1+m2+f1+f2*. And because *m3'* and *m4'* override changes in *m1* and *m2*, you are getting conflict.

The solution is to *rebase* the fixed_toolbar onto the rebased more_design branch. Either as

```
git checkout fixed_toolbar
git rebase --onto more_design original_more_design
```

or by using interactive merge and manually deleting the revisions m1 and m2 if git does not recognize them; it often does:

```
git checkout fixed_toolbar
git rebase -i more_design
```

and only than merging. Or cherry-picking the changes in fixed_toolbar; Recent git should understand

```
git cherry-pick original_more_design..fixed_toolbar
```

Comment: Got it. To apply the changes then I was able to go into fixed_toolbar, create a patch for the revisions I knew were new, and then applied them in my rebased branch.